# Runtime error when accessing private class with dynamic in C#

Tags: dynamic

I'm encountering a runtime error when trying to access a private class using the dynamic keyword. I'd like to keep MyClass as private but still be able to access it using dynamic if possible. Any idea on how to work around it?

```
namespace ConsoleApp
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var myList = new List<MyClass>() { new MyClass(), new MyClass() };
            Helper.CountMethod(myList);
        }

        private class MyClass { }
    }

    public static class Helper
    {
        public static void CountMethod<T>(T target)
        {
            dynamic targetD = target;
            var count = targetD.Count;      // Error: Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: ''object' does not contain a definition for 'Count''
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense. It is a static void method. What is the purpose of counting the list since you do absolutely nothing with the count? Also you are not erroring on MyClass - you are passing a List of MyClass, and it is the list object that is not being recognized as having a Count method (and again, you don't need a helper method to create a count for a list ... lists already have a count method).

Comment: I understand that the code snippet I provided may seem simplified and lacking context. In reality, the purpose of the method is to update the properties of a list of class objects based on the Count, which is why it is a static Helper. While I agree that lists already have a Count property, the example was intended to illustrate the issue I encountered when trying to access properties of a list of objects of private class. The core of my question is how to work around the runtime error I faced when attempting to access the property (like Count) of a list of private class using dynamic.

Comment: Well, if you are passing a list your function should be `CountMethod<T>(List<T> target)`, not `CountMethod<T>(T target)` An example using an appropriate reason for using dynamic would help a lot - the solution here is to just not do what you are doing. Offhand, it seems to me that a nested private class is just that - private. You can't access it outside of the containing class. I wouldn't expect a conversion to dynamic to subvert the semantics of private scope.